# azure service app .net framework 4.6.1

Tags: performance, azure, .net-framework-version

I have an MVC application deployed on Azure as a service app. I switched from .NET framework 4.5 to 4.6.1 and after the deploy i started facing issues of "slowness".
My web application uses Windsor Castle for dependency injection and standard libraries for Azure Storage management, Service bus etc.

The scenario is: each call to the action methods starts getting real slow and from application insight i can see that it tooks sometimes 20 minutes to get a final response even if all the time is spent in getting handled by the application (the time spent inside each action method is real small).

I'm trying to find which is the reason why some action methods are getting slow anyway, is there a way to truncate the processing so that the application can handle new incoming requests without saturing the queue?

Do you have any advice / ideas about why my application started having such behaviour?

Thanks

stefano

Comment: Impossible to tell from our perspective. *without saturing the queue* -> what queue?

Comment: Do you mean "app service"? Need to be specific! There are currently way too many variables here, if you can debug locally calling the same external services, can you tell what is actually taking too long? Can you use Mini Profiler or something to display the slow parts? Is App Insights showing any exceptions (e.g. time outs followed by retries?)

Comment: It's Azure "app service". The point is that App Insights is not showing any exception. I placed a "System.Diagnostics.Trace.TraceInformation(diagnostic);" at the very beginning of the action method and App Insights reveals that between the call to the method and this Trace it takes many seconds even if there's nothing happening (variable definition etc.) and this time get increased when the number of calls to the method increases.